# mod_rewrite in vHost and SSL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

Im searching the whole web but i dont find a solution for my problem.

My server is debian 7.7 with apache2.2. I have a lot of vhost and one SSL cert. All Domains are pointing to the same directory (/var/www/www). For example i have the following domains:

- www.domain.gv.at
- www.domain.at
- www.example.at
- www.anotherexample.at

I would moving all .htaccess stuff to their vhost.

First of all i would redirect www.domain.gv.at www.domain.at domain.gv.at domain.at to https. My .htaccess file looks like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.gv\.at [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.gv\.at [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.at [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.at/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

also I would like pretty URL (i.e. https://www.domain.at/cool/page) so i have the following in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Now I'm trying to copy all in my vHost config without success. My vHost (port 80) looks like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.at
    ServerAlias domain.at domain.gv.at www.domain.gv.at

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.domain.at-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.domain.at-access.log vhost_combined_ip

    <Directory /var/www/www>
      Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.gv\.at [NC,OR]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.gv\.at [NC,OR]
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.at [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.at/$1 [R=301,L]

      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
      RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* /index.php


    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

my vhost for ssl

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/COMODOSSLCA.crt

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
    SSLInsecureRenegotiation off

    ServerName www.domain.at
    ServerAlias domain.at domain.gv.at www.domain.gv.at *.domain.at

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.at-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.at-access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/www>
      Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews -Indexes
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work. Some ideas?

Goals
- delete .htaccess (I don't want to use it)
- redirect domain.at and domain.gv.at to https://
- use pretty urls for typo3

thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

i could solve the problem. In my case the directory was wrong. I have no idea why but it works now after i remove the  in the vHost (SSL and "normal")